# Twilio video: recording rooms server-side

Tags: twilio, webrtc, video-recording, twilio-video

Context: we're building a HIPAA-compliant video chat, and evaluating Twilio as a potential supplier for video streams. Part of the requirement is that we need to make a recording on each video -and this needs to be stored encrypted in a HIPAA-compliant storage.

Having set up Twilio's excelent quickstart example, I've started a server, and were able to connect with two clients to it, with videos.  However, looking around Twilio's room configuration, the server-side recording appears to refer to Twilio-based storage, which is not HIPAA-compliant.

Question: In what ways can we configure the started Node server to save a local copy of all streams participating in a room?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set up a group room based video chat using Twilio Video all participants in the chat make WebRTC connections to a Twilio server in order to transmit and receive data via the room. When you turn on recording, the video that passes through the server is then written to disk. As far as I'm aware, this is not HIPAA compliant.

We do have a page on [building HIPAA compliant video applications with Twilio Video](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180988-Building-HIPAA-Compliant-Video-Applications-with-Twilio) but the advice is to use peer to peer rooms so that the only media that potentially goes through Twilio (via the TURN relay) is encrypted and can't be read or saved by Twilio.

You can't record the video on the Node server from the quickstart, because that's not used to stream the media at all. It only exists to generate an access token.

You could build a server that also joined the peer to peer room of the chat and saved the video that way. I have no experience in building WebRTC server applications though, so I can't help guide you with that. It's certainly not a case of just configuring the server differently.

Your other option would be to record the video in the client and somehow transfer that to your server. That might be unwieldy though for long chats that would cause extra work on the client and result in a potentially large video file to send to the server.